# JavaScript Code Optimization: how to add common code with every method in .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

**Sorry! I couldn't think of a better title, new to the javascript world.**

I have an `abc.js` file and want to add `TestFilter` with every `it` method. Currently, I'm using the below-shown method. Instead of writing `TestFilter` in front of every, `it` method is there any optimized way to achieve this? Please suggest

```
import TestFilter from '../support/TestFilter';

 describe('Test A', () => {

    TestFilter(['smoke'],()=>it.only('should run test A successfully', () => {
      expect(1 + 1).to.be.equal(2);
    }));

    TestFilter(['regression'],()=> it('should run test A successfully', () => {
      expect(1 + 1).to.be.equal(2);
    }));
  });
```

TestFilter.js

```
const TestFilter = (definedTags, runTest) => {
  if (Cypress.env('testtag')) {
    const tags = Cypress.env('testtag').split(',');
    const isFound = definedTags.some((definedTag) => tags.includes(definedTag));
  
    if (isFound) {
      runTest();
    }
  }else{
    runTest();
  }
  
};

export default TestFilter;
```

Comment: Please post an example of how you want your code to appear.

Comment: Your `TestFilter` calls are supplying different filter values - how else would you express the filter rules for each test otherwise?

Comment: Also, what testing framework or library is this?

Comment: @Dai This is cypress framework. Filtering is happening based on the provided tags through cmd at runtime. For better understanding, I have added TestFilter.js file.

Comment: If this is working, then I think it looks good as it is

Comment: @John Existing code is working fine. I thought if there a way that I avoid writing TestFilter with every it method.

Comment: @Dai I just want code to be in a more consolidated way so I don't have to add TestFilter with every it method. I thought of using decorator but not sure how to do that.

Comment: Are you looking for something to avoid calling 'it' as a callback? Then you should have a look at promises.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea for selectively running tests, which is difficult to do.

Here's my (slight) optimisation.

**test**

```
 /* For checking out the extension - normally set externally */
 Cypress.env('testTags', 'regression')
 // Cypress.env('testTags', 'smoke')
 // Cypress.env('testTags', 'smoke,regression')
 // Cypress.env('testTags', null)

 itByTag(['smoke'], 'should run with SMOKE tag', () => {
   expect(1 + 1).to.be.equal(2);
 });

 itByTag(['regression'], 'should run with REGRESSION tag #1', () => {
   expect(1 + 1).to.be.equal(2);
 });

 itByTag.only(['regression'], 'should run with REGRESSION tag #2', () => {
   expect(1 + 1).to.be.equal(2);
 });

 itByTag(['smoke', 'regression'], 'should run with SMOKE and REGRESSION tags', () => {
   expect(1 + 1).to.be.equal(2);
 });
```

**itByTag.js support file**

```
const itByTag = (tags, description, callback) => {
  _itByTag(tags, description, callback)
};

// Adding 'only' extension
itByTag.only = (tags, description, callback) => {
  _itByTag(tags, description, callback, 'only')
};

// Adding 'skip' extension
itByTag.skip = (tags, description, callback) => {
  _itByTag(tags, description, callback, 'skip')
};

// internal implementation
const _itByTag = (tags, description, callback, onlyOrSkip) => {
  const tagsToRun = Cypress.env('testTags');
  const shouldRun = !tagsToRun || 
    tags.some(tag => tagsToRun.split(',').includes(tag));
  if (shouldRun) {
    const itFn = onlyOrSkip ? it[onlyOrSkip] : it;
    itFn(description, callback)
  }
};

export default itByTag;
```

Comment: One problem with is lack of `it.only()` and `it.skip()`, which your syntax can handle.

Comment: I think that is also possible in your answer. Just add only/skip tag in tag array/description and check in itByTg method if tag array/description has only/skip. Then use if else to call it.only or it.skip

Comment: My preference is to keep tags as tags and description as description, in fact `.only()` and `.skip()` should follow the convention used by standard `it`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a certain piece of code to run before each of your tests, you can try 'beforeEach' hook in mocha. Although I am not sure if cypress supports mocha hooks.

Comment: Cypress supports mocha hook. I have posted the example code above, can you tell me how hooks can help in this scenario?